# Python FLASK API getting error when trying to POST

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on creating an API using Python and FLASK. The GET requests are working correctly. However I am trying to test my POST request using Postman.

Here is my method:

```
@app.route('/createlogin', methods=['POST'])
def create_login():
    try:        
        _json = request.json
        _username = _json['username']
        _password = _json['password']
        if _username and _password and request.method == 'POST':
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)        
            sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO user_logins(username, password) VALUES(%s, %s)"
            bindData = (_username, _password)            
            cursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            conn.commit()
            respone = jsonify('Employee added successfully!')
            respone.status_code = 200
            return respone
        else:
            return showMessage()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()
```

Here is how my Postman request is set up:
[image]

Here is the exact error I am getting:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.
[2023-09-30 09:47:49,251] ERROR in app: Exception on /createlogin [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Codeing\API\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Codeing\API\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Codeing\API\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Codeing\API\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Codeing\API\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Codeing\API\main.py", line 30, in create_login
    cursor.close()
    ^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'cursor' where it is not associated with a value
```

I've tried searching up similar problems however all the problems I am finding relate to trying to access an API instead of the error being in the API itself.

Comment: `cursor` is only defined if the `if` condtion is matched, but it is referenced in the `finally` clause that is always executed.  Move the declaration of cursor outside of the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue, it was a stupid mistake but I am keeping it up just in case anyone else runs into this issue.

In my snippet of Postman you can see I am under body and selected raw. On the far right where it says text, click that drop-down and switch it to JSON.